# selectedColumn in NSTableView returns -1

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I get the selected row number correctly, but the selected column returns -1.

```
- (void) tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    int row = [[notification object] selectedRow];
    int column = [[notification object] selectedColumn];
```

Comment: How are you selecting the row? Because the value of -1 indicates that no column is selected.

Answer (score 0):

First thing `tableviewselectiondidchange` will always give you selected rows index. You can see in `NSTableviewdelegate` reference methods. If you want both rows and column index then use this api

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView*)tableView shouldTrackCell:(NSCell *)cell    forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
```